# Get First And Last Day Of Year

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-2013

In VBA I know you can use this syntax to subtract a year from a date

```
Dim testdate As String, DateTest As String
testdate= "03/21/2017"
DateTest = Month(testdate) & "/" & Day(testdate) & "/" & Year(testdate) - 1
```

But how could you find the first and last date of a given year?  For example, let's use the same date

```
testdate = "03/21/2017"
```

and get the following values

```
firstdate = "01/01/2017"
lastdate = "12/31/2017"
```

Comment: you can use a combination of `Year`, and `EOMonth`

Comment: I strongly urge you to consider using `Date` data types when working with dates - using `String` types will cause you so much grief in the future that it is better to change now.

Comment: @YowE3K - the dates are being input into a user form text box.  Can I have a date type for this or must it be string since it is a text box?

Comment: It probably needs to be a String in the text box, but you should convert to a `Date` as soon as possible once the user has entered it. Something like `Dim myDate As Date` `If Not IsDate(TextBox1.Text) Then MsgBox "Not a date": Exit Sub Else myDate = CDate(TextBox1.Text)`.  That would allow the user to enter something like "27 March 2017" into the text box and `MyDate` would be set to the `Date` `27/03/2017` (or `03/27/2017` if you think in terms of "mm/dd/yyyy" dates) which can then be used in any date-related calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is always the beginning and the end of the year that interest you, you can just use the 1st of January and the 31st of december. To mimic your syntax :

```
Dim testdate As String, DateTest As String
testdate= "03/21/2017"
FirstDayOfYear = "1/1/" & Year(testdate)
LastDayOfYear = "12/31/" & Year(testdate)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `DateSerial`:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim dt As Date, firstDay As Date, lastDay As Date

    dt = Date
    firstDay = DateSerial(Year(dt), 1, 1)
    lastDay = DateSerial(Year(dt), 12, 31)

    Debug.Print firstDay
    Debug.Print lastDay

End Sub
```